# Python HTML Email : How to insert list items in HTML email

Tags: python, smtplib

I tried hard to find solution to this issues but all in vein, finally i have to ask you guys. I have HTML email (using Python's smtplib). Here is the code

```
Message = """From: abc@abc.com>
To: abc@abc.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: test

Hello,
Following is the message 
""" + '\n'.join(mail_body)  + """
Thank you.
"""
```

In above code, mail_body is a list which contains lines of output from a process. Now what i want is, to display these lines (line by line) in HTML email. What is happening now its just appending line after line. i.e.

I am storing the output(of process) like this :

```
for line in cmd.stdout.readline()
    mail_body.append()
```

Current Output in HTML email is:

```
Hello,
abc
Thank you.
```

What i want :

```
Hello,
a
b
c
Thank you.
```

I just want to attach my process output in HTML email line by line. Can my output be achieved in any way?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in HTML, a new line is not `\n` it is `<br>` for "line break" but since you are also not using HTML tags in this email, you also need to know that in MIME messages, a newline is `\r\n` and not just `\n`

So you should write:

```
'\r\n'.join(mail_body)
```

For newlines that deal with the MIME message, but if you are going to use the HTML for formatting, then you need to know that `<br>` is the line break, and it would be:

```
'<br>'.join(mail_body)
```

To be comprehensive, you could try:

```
'\r\n<br>'.join(mail_body)
```

But I do now know what that would like like...

Comment: I was pondering if the the OP is really after `<p>some paragraph tags</p>`

Comment: Awesome, You are awesome, May god bless you with sweet kids and lot of money. "<b>" worked for me, and i want nothing else. I don't know why i didn't thought of this simple thing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you don't need `"\r\n"`: `smtplib` translates `\n` (or `\r`) for you. Otherwise you would need to worry about `\r\n.\r\n`, `From `, 7-bit cleanness, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could generate the email content to send using [`email` package (from stdlib) e.g.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from cgi import escape
from email.header import Header
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL

login, password = 'me@example.com', 'my password'

# create message
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = Header('subject…', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = login
msg['To'] = ', '.join([login,])

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hello,\nFollowing is the message\n%(somelist)s\n\nThank you." % dict(
    somelist='\n'.join(["- " + item for item in mail_body]))

html = """<!DOCTYPE html><title></title><p>Hello,<p>Following is the message 
<ul>%(somelist)s</ul><p>Thank you. """ % dict(
    somelist='\n'.join(["<li> " + escape(item) for item in mail_body]))

# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain', 'utf-8'))
msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8'))    

# send it
s = SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.example.com', timeout=10) # no cert check on Python 2

s.set_debuglevel(0)
try:
    s.login(login, password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
finally:
    s.quit()
```